# $G$ is a group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $[G : H]=2$. Suppose $a, b \in G$, but neither $a$ nor $b$ are in $H$. Prove $ab \in H$.

Tags: group-theory

So far what I've come up with is that since $[G : H]=2$, $G$ can be represented as two left cosets: one of which is just $H$, and then one that is $gH$ for some $g$ in $G$. So $a$ and $b$ must be in this second coset. Then one property of cosets is that if $a$ is in $G$, and $b$ is in $aH$, then $aH=bH$. So assume $ab$ is in $gH$, then $abH = gH$, but $a$ does not exist in $abH$, so this is a contradiction, and therefore $ab$ must reside in $H$. Does this make sense, or am I making false assumptions?

Comment: Your reasoning is OK, I guess you understand that if you say "$a$ does not exist in $abH$" you know why this is the case, right?

Answer (score 5):

You can write it more crisply as follows: if $ab \notin H$, then $G = H \cup abH$. Since $a \notin H$, it follows that $a \in abH$, so $a=abh$ for some $h\in H$. But then $b=h^{-1} \in H$, a contradiction.